# React Redux skeleton returning undefined for value from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

Here's the code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lp005rj59q

I'm expecting it to display Hello  Goodbye , but it's just showing Goodbye

I'm building the skeleton for a new React/Redux app that I'm working on and `<h1>{value}</h1>` returns undefined. I know this because I put console.log(value) between my render and return method in my class.

I've 
Mapped State to props:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.value
});
```

Created my store:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(reducers);

export default store;
```

Created my reducer with initial state of "Hello"

```
const initialState = {
  value: "Hello"
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

created a connect function:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Clock);
```

Added value to this.props:

```
export class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    console.log(value);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{value}</h1>
        <h2> Goodbye</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and passed the store to the provider element:

```
const AppWrapper = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Clock />
  </Provider>
);

render(<AppWrapper />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting two `React` components from **Clock.js**:

1. Presentational component `Clock` as named export `Clock`
2. Container component which is the result of connecting your presentational component `Clock` to `redux` via `connect` function. It's default export.

But in **index.js** you're importing just that presentational component `Clock`:

```
import {Clock} from "./Clock";
```

Instead you should import container component:

```
import Clock from "./Clock";
```

Please pay attention to absence of curly braces. You can read more about `es6` modules on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: That did it, thank you! I think I actually had it like that, changed it to test and never changed it back. I think I may have fixed whatever the issue used to be and never noticed because I never switched back to the correct import. I'll be sure to keep in mind the difference between presentational and container imports.